# Avoid iframed URL being used by others

Tags: javascript, iframe, token

I plan to provide stock quote function by iframe-ing a 3rd party stock information provider site, but the site requires a dynamic token to control access quota.
How to avoid others from using the underlying iframe url of my site instead of using the function through my site?
Can other site use Javascript to access my site behind the scene, then get my dynamic token, and use that token to launch the 3rd party function on their site?
If yes, are their any way to avoid my quota being stolen?

Comment: Depends if third party also includes headers that only allow that token to be displayed on specific domain. Currently not enough known

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean checking the referrer? But is there any way to spoof that header?

Comment: No because it is set by remote site if it exists. Again it depends if such frame buster protections exist in third party page

Comment: It does not exist now but we can request them to add